# I am a Zimbabwean and have stayed in South Africa for 60 days. How long do I have to exit the country before returning?

Tags: south-africa, zimbabwean-citizens

I have been doing a bunch of yachting courses here in South Africa and would like to know if I can exit and re-enter South Africa on the same day to get a new visa?

Comment: How much longer do you want to stay? You should have been allowed 90 days to begin with. From [this question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/45156/can-i-leave-south-africa-before-my-90-days-expire-and-return-after-a-few-days-t), it looks like you could do a visa run, but you would have to return to Zimbabwe or a country that doesn't share a border with SA.