# Can I re-enter South Africa for a second time from the UK within my 90 day SA visitor visa limit?

Tags: visas, uk-citizens, visa-free-entry, south-africa, 90-180-visa-rules

I am a UK citizen, Can I re-enter South Africa for a second time after returning home to the UK, if the second visit to South Africa is still within the first visit's allocated 90 day time limit? Will they let me back into the country on this 1st visa or will I be re-issued a new visa, as I have returned to my home country in between? I can't seem to find any info about this anywhere about returning home and then re-entering South Africa again after a couple of weeks. I've already booked my return flight to SA from UK but panicking slightly that they'll let me back into the country...Im just going back for 2 weeks Thanks

Comment: Each time a visa-free national is allowed to enter they are given a new entry stamp, you cannot re-enter on a previous stamp even if you’re within the time given. How long did you stay on your first trip to S.A.? Why are you returning so soon (typical vacation travellers don’t do that) and what is the purpose of your second visit? Visa-free nationals require a visa in some instances eg medical treatment http://www.dha.gov.za/index.php/immigration-services/types-of-visas

Comment: Different timeframe for OP’s return visit but possible duplicate of [Can I leave South Africa before my 90 days expire, and return after a few days to stay for another 90 days?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/45156/can-i-leave-south-africa-before-my-90-days-expire-and-return-after-a-few-days-t)