# I have a UK passport, can I leave South Africa to visit Kenya and return to South Africa during the 90 day Holiday visa?

Tags: visas, uk-citizens, visa-free-entry, south-africa, kenya

I’m visiting South Africa on a UK passport and then traveling to Kenya for a short trip before returning to South Africa to continue my holiday. Is my 90 day Holiday visa valid for the return?

Comment: Do you have a visa for Kenya? Related question re South Africa exit/reentry https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/45156/can-i-leave-south-africa-before-my-90-days-expire-and-return-after-a-few-days-t

Comment: In the process of getting one.

Answer (score 6):

If your 90 days is still in date when you go to reenter South Africa, you will be admitted on that same 90 days, if not you will be granted no more than 7 days. Note that the 90 days do not pause when you leave the country.

Alternatively, you can apply for a multiple entry visa, and this will allow you to leave and come back into South Africa, but only after you apply for your visa for Kenya.

> **[Can I request a multiple entry visa?](https://www.vfsglobal.com/southafrica/uk/faqs.html)**
>
> You can request a multiple entry visa, however you must provide a
>   motivational letter stating the reasons/justification for your
>   request. Please also provide flight/travel reservation documentation,
>   hotel reservations and details of full travel itinerary. Please note
>   that travel/hotel bookings should be provisional only and not
>   confirmed.
>
> Please also provide visas to all countries of intended visit for the
>   current trip, original and copies. For example, if you are travelling
>   to South Africa and intend on visiting a neighbouring country such as
>   Botswana within the same trip, you must provide your visa for Botswana
>   or documented proof that you have applied for this visa. If visas have
>   been applied for, please provide the relevant documentation as proof. Alternatively, if you do not require a visa to any of the neighbouring
>   countries, please provide proof of exemption.