# Can I leave South Africa for a week and then come back for another three months?

Tags: visas, africa, tourism, visitor

I'm a Venezuelan visiting South Africa and I'm planning to stay longer since I met my boyfriend here and he want me to stay for another three months visiting him, but since my visitor visa is about to expire, I want to go to Spain for a week to visit a friend and then come back to the country.

That does apply for another three months? Asking because it's insanely expensive to go back to Venezuela and then come back to South Africa. I'm choosing Spain because I can afford the tickets, but isn't the same with Venezuela.

I'm asking because everyone, even in the Department of Home Affairs, says something different. Some people says I have to go back to Venezuela, some people says that isn't necessary. Even my boyfriend says I can go to any country (except Namibia, Zambia, etc) and then come back.

Really need to know because I already booked the tickets to go to Spain.

Regards!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I leave South Africa before my 90 days expire, and return after a few days to stay for another 90 days?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/45156/can-i-leave-south-africa-before-my-90-days-expire-and-return-after-a-few-days-t)

Comment: If the [2014 version of the regulations](https://www.vfsglobal.com/dha/southafrica/pdf/final-Immigration-Regulations-2014-1.pdf) is still in effect, a visa run will get you only 7 days more. You can only get the full 90 days from your country of residence.

Comment: Hey! I saw the answers to that question but I still confused since there's two different opinions about it. One says about the 7 days thing and the other one says I can go to any place in the world and then I can have 90 days. I went to the DHA and asked them, they didn't even know. It's a bit frustrating.

Comment: It's difficult to find an authoritative source for the current, consolidated version of the Immigration Act, but I haven't found any changes since the 2014 version which makes it clear that returning before the end of the original visa -> you get the same, after that -> you get only 7 days, unless you "arrive from your country of residence". The [exemption information page on DHA website](http://www.dha.gov.za/index.php/immigration-services/exempt-countries) does not say anything about it.

Comment: Thank you! I'm just praying and hoping for the best at this point. At least I can entry the country again, that's also important, but it's frustrating because we've looking for information and asking, and everyone says something different.

Comment: Note that border officers usually don't like visa runs very much, and they are bound to ask a lot of questions: how can you afford to be away from home for so long, how do you support yourself, are you not working while in South Africa, etc. Entry is never guaranteed.

Comment: Just to clarify, when I wrote "returning before the end of the original visa -> you get the same" I meant that you remain on the original visa, not that you get a new one of the same duration. So if the visa expires on the 30th, you leave on the 10th, you come back on the 20th, you still have to leave before the 30th.

Comment: Gotcha! Thank you so much for your answers.

Comment: It seems the 2014 version of the regulations is still in effect, so the rule still applies: you have to go back to your country of residence to get 90 more days (but again, subject to approval by the border officer).

Comment: Thank you. Seems like I have to go to Venezuela then, I didn't want to because it's too expensive but it's my safe option.

Comment: @JuliaMendoza As jcaron mentions, even if you do go back to Venezuela visa-free re-entry into SA for another 90 days is at the discretion of the border officer, it is not 100% guaranteed. Most tourists can’t spend months at a time away from responsibilities like a job, family etc in their home country. If you return after spending only a short time in your home country, you should be prepared for questions the border officer might ask you to establish whether you are a regular visitor eg the reason(s) for a rapid return, how you will support yourself while in SA.