# South Africa 90 day travel rules

Tags: south-africa

Can you leave South Africa on day 85 of 90 days travel to Botswana or surrounding for a week and than return back to SA because that is where the flight is out of Johannesburg back to US?

Comment: For completeness, what’s your citizenship? Also, will that length of time in Botswana or wherever be enough to enable you to comply with any Covid-related entry requirements on your return to SA eg proof of PCR test?

Comment: Unless you add details to proof it is a different question, this will be closed as a duplicate of the question where you also posted this in an answer spot. https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/4911/i-dont-need-a-visa-for-a-stay-under-90-days-in-south-africa-but-can-i-enter-sa

Comment: If you just need to add a few days to your stay, have you considered contacting the Department of Home Affairs or the Immigration services in South Africa https://www.gov.za/services/temporary-residence/temporary-residency

Comment: Note that there are relatively recent rules which prevent “visa runs” to neighbouring countries, so the accepted answer linked to above is no longer valid. I don’t know the exact terms of those rules (and there’s conflicting info out there), but it lay indeed affect your plans, especially if your passage in South Africa on your way back home extends beyond the original 90 days.